Understanding Homebrew's "leaves" command
I have setup my Mac in somewhat usual way: I have created a user admin which has administration privileges, and I work my myself under a non-admin account. I use this setup out of a habit from my past in Unix and Linux, and I have learned that this is not ideal problems on the Mac, and actually resulted to a puzzling behaviour of homebrew.
Usually, I run brew under the admin user (i.e. doing a su admin, and then install the packages with brew).
I now noticed a behaviour with brew, which I would like to understand:
When I run - as myself - the command
brew leaves

I see all the installed packages, and I also get an error message
rm: /usr/local/Homebrew/.git/describe-cache: Permission denied

The message itself is not surprising:
ls -ld /usr/local/Homebrew/.git/describe-cache

shows
drwxr-xr-x  3 admin  admin  96  3 Sep 08:41 /usr/local/Homebrew/.git/describe-cache

brew leaves obviously wants to remove this directory, and since I installed my packages with brew under the admin user, I have no permission when doing this as normal user.
So out of curiosity, I did a su admin to become admin, and run the brew leaves command again. As expected, no error message this time.
However when I look again at the directory, I see that it has still the same timestamp as before! It seems that brew did not even attempt any deletion this time.
It is as if brew tries to erase the directory only if it is not run as admin user.
Could someone give me an explanation of what happens here?

I don't see why brew leaves wants to delete anything.  What does brew doctor tell you? I would expect you to do all installs (include brew commands) as an admin user - so why do you want to run brew commands as non-admin user?

@Gilby : The only reason I want to run brew leaves is to provide as a report a list of all packages installed on this machine. This report is run as part of a housekeeping routine, and the error message is not a real problem; it just doesn't look nice, so I got curious and wanted to understand what is going on.

Strange…  I too have homebrew set up from my admin user.  When I run brew leaves from my normal user, it prints nothing at all!  (Except the first time, when it downloaded a couple of tap-related formulas.)  Other brew commands (such as desc and search fail with Ruby-related error messages, though brew list seems to work fine.  — I simply assumed that brew shouldn't be run from any other user.

Homebrew is designed to be run as the current user so using more than one user might well have issues.
